# How do I exit a True loop and move on to the next piece of code in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am wondering:

First, is it possible to exit a
`while True` loop and move onto the next piece of code? This is my
`while True` code that I am using:

```py
while True:
  b = input("Which row of transition metals would you like to find out the melting and boiling points of? ")
  print("")
  if b == "1" or b == "1st" or b == "first" or b == "First":
    print("First row of transition metals:")
    slg(listA, a)
    again = input("Continue? ")
    if again == "yes":
      continue
  elif b == "2" or b == "2nd" or b == "second" or b == "Second":
    print("Second row of transition metals:")
    slg(listB, a)
    again = input("Continue? ")
    if again == "yes":
      continue
```

Is it possible so that if I had `if again == no`, it would move on to the next piece of code, exiting the `while True` loop?

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: `if again == "no": break`

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` statement to exit out of the `while` loop. It works with `for` loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `break` keyword is used to exit a loop. Note that you don't need to repeat code that asks for continuation; you can write it once *after* your `if` statement.

```
while True:
    b = input("Which row of transition metals would you like to find out the melting and boiling points of? ")
    print("")

    if b == "1" or b == "1st" or b == "first" or b == "First":
        print("First row of transition metals:")
        slg(listA, a)
    elif b == "2" or b == "2nd" or b == "second" or b == "Second":
        print("Second row of transition metals:")
        slg(listB, a)
    else:
        # Without a valid response, ask again
        continue

    # Only ask to continue or break after a valid response
    again = input("Continue? ")
    if again != "yes":
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use approach like this, where you set the conditional variable true at begining  then in code when the condition to set code exit come make that variable False

Below is a example code

```
 cond = True
 while cond:
        // some code
        if <condition>:
                continue
        else:
               cond = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count =1

while True:
    print("Inside while loop")
    for i in "python":
        if i == "h":
            count = 5
            break
        else:
            print(i)
    if count == 5:
        break
```

Please have a look at the above code.
The output for the above code is -

```
Inside while loop
p
y
t
```

The above code shows that the keyword `break` can be used to exit from for and while loops. 
The keyword `continue` takes it to the to the beginning of the while loop. The `continue` statement rejects all the remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop and moves the control back to the top of the loop.

From what you asked, `if again == no`, if this is provided you can exit from the while loop if you give something like this

```
if again == no:
     break
```

But if you just give the below code,

```
if again == no:
    continue
```

it will still be in the while loop.

Hope this helps.